# python+tkinter:Multidimensional listbox using Tkinter widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, listbox, tkinter

Hey can anybody help me to create a multidimensional listbox using Tkinter Listbox widget.For example consdier any inhouse organizational directory thus on execution the listbox should be able to print Name vs Extension as shown below:

> Rahul 123
>
> Pratik 212
>
> ...

Currently when i use the listbox widget each entry is printed in new lines like:

> Rahul
>   123
>   Pratik
>   122..

But i wanted to print it side by side, multidimensional view.

Comment: What do the input lists look like?

Comment: @atlasologist there is no input list.the list is populated dynamically from an excel sheet.The code based on certain comparisons fetch the name of the person and its telephone extension number and print it in the form of list.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand. You can `zip()` two lists if they have a one-to-one relationship, or you can combine two lists based on criteria--I don't know enough about the problem to help. Maybe try adding some code so we can get a bigger picture?

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you, if you have two lists

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

x = ["1","2","3","4"] 
y = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]   

for i in range(len(y)):
    z = y[i] + " " + x[i]
    listbox.insert(END, z)

mainloop()
```